# Fade through image in CCSprite?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Is it possible to fade through the images in a CCSprite? Currently I only know its possible to fade through objects in Cocos2D but I wasn't sure if this was possible or not.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Fade" usually means to change the transparency of an image. Something tells me this is not what you mean. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Hmm, I want to change the image in my CCSprite not immediately, I want to animate the change through images. I guess the term transform works here :P

Comment: Also I want to achieve this with one CCSprite because the answerer below wants me to uses multiple sprites which makes things 100% harder for me.

Comment: What you mean is an animation, ie animating a sprite. Fade relates to transparency, transform means "changing the position".

Comment: Correct! So how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use `CCFadeOut` to remove your current image, while, at the same time, create your new sprite at the same position with opacity 0, and make it fade in with `CCFadeIn`. If you do it at the same time, you should get a nice effect.

Comment: How could I achieve this with one sprite?

Comment: How do you expect to "fade through images" if you only got one anyway?

Comment: I don't know that's why I need advice :P It must be possible!

Comment: I don't think your question is properly formulated. Try to use different words instead, because I think I'm not getting what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can fade with 2 CCSprites through multiple images.

1. CCSprite A to opaque to the front zOrder 1
2. CCSprite B to transparent (if CCSprite A covers the CCSprite B then this is not needed), zOrder 0
3. FadeOut CCSprite A and after that put it in the background, zOrder 0
4. CCSprite B zOrder 1 in the front, it is seen after point 2
5. Exchange image of CCSprite A to every uneven
6. repeat everything, this time give the argument of CCSprite A and B in opposite order

Exchange the sprite:

```
CCCallBlock *exchangeImage = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    sprite.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"image.png"];
}];
```

Add delay if needed:

```
CCDelayTime *delayAction = [[CCDelayTime alloc] initWithDuration:0.4f];
```

Put together an repeat:

```
CCSequence *exchangeSequence = [CCSequence actions:exchangeImage, delayAction, nil];
CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:exchangeSequence];
[self runAction:repeat];
```